# Fixed picture to the bottom

Tags: html, css

How should I make the picture to be in the bottom, with 20 px away from the bottom, and not in the middle?

Thanks!

```css
.overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
#aaa {
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#aaa:hover {
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <a href="" id="aaa"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height` and set the `bottom` to `20px`

```css
.overlay {
position: fixed;
bottom: 20px;
left: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
#aaa {
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#aaa:hover {
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <a href="" id="aaa"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While other answer does the trick, I'm guessing you need that overlay to be 100% height. Cuz that's what overlays are about so you should add

```
 position:fixed;
 bottom:10px;
```

to `#aaa`

```css
.overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
#aaa {
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:10px;
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#aaa:hover {
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-drink-3/512/Candy-128.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <a href="" id="aaa"></a>
</div>
```